# Win10 IOT / UWP: How to detect if a network device (Arduino) is availabe

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'd like to connect if my Arduino is available on the network. I'm trying to access the Arduino web server using an HTTP client and processing the JSON answer.

Since ping is not available in UWP what are my options? (see: [Article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/45e75273-2b87-44cd-86f8-84eb8b285a05/uwpcusing-systemnetping-in-uwp-app-vs-2017?forum=wpdevelop))

One option would be to handle the exception of the HTTP client. But is there any more elegant way to check the connection before requesting the JSON data?

Comment: Wouldn't I2C be a lot easier?

Answer (score 0):

One method might be using the HTTPClient to do a GetAsync() and check the Status code coming out of it.

Depending on your time constraints, you can wait for it to time out naturally or pass a cancellation token to break it sooner than the defaults.

From here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient (slightly modified):

```
//Send the GET request asynchronously and retrieve the response as a string.

Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
string httpResponseBody = "";

try
{
    //Send the GET request
    httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
    if(httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) { /* Do something with it */ }
    else { /* Do fallback here */ }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: That is my current solution already - I thought there might be something more elegant out there.